# Laravel 5.4 mix issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I installed a fresh laravel 5.4 application. I followed the documentation on how to set up laravel mix. However, when I run npm run dev i get the following error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.8.6
3 info using node@v5.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 silly lifecycle @~predev: no script for predev, continuing
7 info lifecycle @~dev: @
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/vagrant/websites/ezskillz/node_modules/.bin:/usr/bin:/home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
10 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /home/vagrant/websites/ezskillz
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c',
11 silly lifecycle   'node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
14 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:239:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
15 verbose pkgid @
16 verbose cwd /home/vagrant/websites/ezskillz
17 error Linux 4.4.0-22-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
19 error node v5.12.0
20 error npm  v3.8.6
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error @ dev: `node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script 'node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

do you have any idea what's going on?

Thank you

Comment: Did you update node / npm?

Comment: How do I do that in homestead? Do I need to install hombrew to update my npm and node?

Comment: I'm not sure as I don't use Homestead, just reading the error log *"Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed"*

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Thanks to Andy Holmes. I had to update my nodejs in homestead running the following commands

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and then I run the following command to rebuild node-sass

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I removed the whole node_modules folder and tried installing packages with yarn instead of npm.

1. Delete the node_modules folder
2. Re-install packages using yarn i.e  `run yarn instead of npm install.`

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You have node and npm if you look at line 2 and 3 you can see

```
2 info using npm@3.8.6
3 info using node@v5.12.0
```

And at line 23 In the mid:

```
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
23 error not with npm itself.
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why it is the case, whether it was a particular version that had a bug which has since been fixed, but to get my fresh laravel 5.4 install working at the time I had to change the paths in package.json from:

```
node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js
```

to

```
node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js
```

note the addition of "dist"

**Edit:**

Actually notice on a newer fresh install the entire

```
node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js
```

line is replaced simply with

```
cross-env
```

So for example:

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"watch-poll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --watch-poll --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```